# RIDE.. Getting [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified when using Robot framework for Android library

Tags: android, python, robotframework

Im trying to build automation test cases using robot framework for android devices.

I have imported the android library and have installed python on my system.

My code is as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           AndroidLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
case1
Start Emulator    avd_name='AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google',no_window=False, language=en,   country=us
Wait For Device    timeout=120
Press Menu Button
Stop Emulator
```

When I try to execute a test case, I get the error:

command: pybot.bat --argumentfile c:\users\kesav\appdata\local\temp\RIDEnhapet.d\argfile.txt --listener C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_ride-1.3-py2.7-win32.egg\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:52956:False C:\Users\kesav\test
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.

I have checked the PATH environment variable, it contains C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts as well.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are missing something from you path, make sure you path has:

```
;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

You are missing site-packages from your path, try that and get back to me!

Comment: I have evrything you mentioned in my Path variable. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the TestRunnerAgent is present at the location you specified?